# Загрузка файла с сервера по запросу пользователя ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net

В моём веб-приложении ASP.NET по клику кнопки генерируется файл xlsx, после генерации необходимо инициировать скачивание файла на компьютер пользователя. Есть ли готовые решения или что-то наподобие?

Comment: Файл xlsx генерируется на сервере или клиенте?

Comment: ASP.NET Web Forms. Веб-приложение развёрнуто на сервере, клиент получает доступ по локальной сети посредством браузера, на сервере генерируется файл.

Comment: Буду пробовать  [это](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/afenster/how-to-download-a-file-in-Asp-Net/)